# How to execute raw sql by flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have multiple datasource in my flask app so I have to use `bind` to specify datasource during sql execution.

The app is running based on python 3.11.7

Due to the latest airflow's dependencies, I have to downgrade some sqlalchemy dependencies like this:

```
apache-airflow==2.8.2

Flask==3.0.0              downgrade to   Flask==2.2.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1   downgrade to   Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
SQLAlchemy==2.0.24        downgrade to   SQLAlchemy==1.4.51
```

Here is the code which was running well before downgrade:

```
db.session.execute(
            text(f"""
                    SELECT
                    *
                    FROM
                    system_role role
                    INNER JOIN system_relation_user_role ur ON ur.role_id = role.id
                    WHERE ur.user_id = {user_id}
                """),
            bind_arguments={"bind": db.get_engine(bind='system')},
        )
```

I found nothing help in [this issue](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/953).

I also find a way to specify `bind` like this:

```
db.get_engine(bind='system').execute(
            text(f"""
                    SELECT
                    *
                    FROM
                    system_role role
                    INNER JOIN system_relation_user_role ur ON ur.role_id = role.id
                    WHERE ur.user_id = {user_id}
                """),
        )
```

But it looks ugly, I don't like to get engine in the business code. Is there any proper way to achive that goal to just specify the `bind`?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks. Never use any kind of string interpolation with SQL.